# Calling platform-specific code in AlarmManager

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a Alarm, which fires once a day and compares two values. If these values are equal, I send a notification. So I created the platform-specific method send_reminder (only Android).

My problem: If I call the Method in the "normal" code while the app is running, everything works fine. But if I try to call the method in an alarm, I get this Exception back.

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method send_reminder on channel reminder_channel)
```

checkForReminders method:

```
void checkForReminders() async{
  print("alarm called");

  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    try {
      var platform = const MethodChannel("reminder_channel");
      final String result =
          await platform.invokeMethod("send_reminder");
      print("Result of platform: $result");
    } catch (e) {
      print("Exception while calling platformspecific code: ");
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

How I setup the alarm in the main.dart:

```
final int dailyAlarmID = 0;
if (firstOpen) {
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
}

runApp(...);

DateTime currentDate = new DateTime.now();

if (firstOpen) {
  AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
      Duration(days: 1), dailyAlarmID, checkForReminders,
      rescheduleOnReboot: true,
      exact: true,
      startAt: DateTime(
          currentDate.year, currentDate.month, currentDate.day, 11, 30, 10));
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity{
  private static final String REMINDERCHANNEL = "reminder_channel";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(),REMINDERCHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(new MethodCallHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onMethodCall(MethodCall methodCall, Result result) {
        result.success("String returned correctly.");
      }
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: did you tried `if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  // Android-specific code
}`

Comment: Could you share minimal code which can help us to try on our own and suggest solution faster?

Comment: Please look at my updated question. If you need more code, just ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check `if(Platform.isAndroid)` before executing the core of `checkForReminders()`

so you will have something similar to this:

```dart
  import 'dart:io';//todo import in top

  checkForReminders() {
    //... other code

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      // Android-specific code
      var platform = const MethodChannel("reminder_channel");
      try {
        //This is just Hello World! String to see if it is working correctly
        final String result = await platform.invokeMethod("send_reminder");
        print("Result of platform: $result");
      } catch (e) {
        print("Exception while calling platformspecific code");
        print(e);
      }
    }

    //... other code
  }
```

Comment: Give me 10 minutes I am going to try it out.

Comment: try to uninstall the app from your device and run `flutter clean`

Comment: Still the same problem. Any idea? By the way, all plugins for example PathProvider are working correctly in the alarm.

Comment: edit you question with the hole dart file which contains `checkForReminders()` and where you setup the alarm

Comment: Checkout my updated code. My  `checkForReminders` method is located below the main method. I hope you can do something with it.